# Broken link to iTunes keeps opening tabs on Firefox

Tags: itunes, firefox, web-browser, url

What is wrong with this link? It keeps opening tabs as fast as it can.

Warning, if you click on it do not blame me:

itmss://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-compressor-just-set/id825584875?mt=8&ign-mscache=1&ign-msr=http%3A%2F%2Fosxdaily.com%2F2017%2F09%2F05%2Fcompress-videos-ios-video-compressor%2F

MacBook OSX up to date
Firefox version 62

Comment: it's only an iTunes link up to the `mt=8` idk what it is after that. The first bit works for me, except the app isn't available in the UK store. Google finds the original OSXDaily page at http://osxdaily.com/2017/09/05/compress-videos-ios-video-compressor/ which then contains the 'correct' link - `https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-compressor-just-set/id825584875?mt=8` which matches the first part of your broken link. Maybe it's meant to be a 'referer' ?

Comment: I didn't risk the full link, btw, just the 'correct' bit & the osxdaily, from 'http', as 2 separate things. First opened iTunes, 2nd went to Google, rather than osxdaily,  which then found the page.